# Refeshring JSP page in Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, page-refresh, dwr

I am trying to refresh the JSP page after certain operations, I am using DWR to be able to use my classes in Javascripts in the JSP files so I have this code:

```
function removeDN(numplanindex){
    DBOps.removeDN(numplanindex);
    relaod(true);
}
```

the above code will break the removeDN() and it would not refresh the page, I have also tried window.location.reload(true) and document.location.reload(true).

I am not sure about the difference as I barely know any Javascript but according to everything on google this should work. I am wondering if anybody know what is wrong with what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Typo mistake in relaod(true); It should be reload

Comment: sorry about the typo, its not how it is in my code its because I typed instead of copy paste. Its reload(true) in my code so its not the typo

Answer (score 1):

It should be reload(true) instead of relaod(true)

Also see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp

Comment: sorry about the typo, its not how it is in my code its because I typed instead of copy paste. Its reload(true) in my code so its not the typo